# Aircrack-NG fundamentals: how much network traffic takes each of the WIFi devices on my wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, aircrack-ng

I have a **portable computer** running Kali Linux near (about 2 meters) to my DSL **wireless access point**, and I am trying to **browse all the traffic** on my network capturing it with [AirCrack-NG](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/).

This is an example of an usual **Aircrack-NG output** for the **four wireless devices** connected to my network:

```
 CH  8 ][ Elapsed: 48 s ][ 2015-06-30 00:37 ][ disabled selection

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSI

 DC:9F:DB:A6:E2:6E  -77  86      404      859    0   8  54e. OPN              Salo

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe

 DC:9F:DB:A6:E2:6E  98:52:B1:E0:18:52   -1    1e- 0      0        1
 DC:9F:DB:A6:E2:6E  6C:2F:2C:56:F9:B3   -1    1e- 0      0      573
 DC:9F:DB:A6:E2:6E  98:3B:16:3C:72:CC   -1    1e- 0      0      239
 DC:9F:DB:A6:E2:6E  B8:76:3F:E3:9C:E7   -1    1e- 0      0       60
```

There are **no cable** RJ45 devices: all of them are wirelessly connected.

Assuming I am **loosing zero wireless traffic** (so the reason to capture in the proximity of the access point) : If the frames (`Frame` field) for each device sum:

```
1+573+239+60 = 873
```

Can I say this down here is the **percentage of bandwith ussage** for each device? :

```
First device:   1/873 =     0,0011454753722795  =   00.11 %
Second device:  573/873 =   0,6563573883161512  =   65.63 %
Third device:   239/873 =   0,2737686139747995  =   27.37 %
First device:   60/873 =    0,0687285223367698  =   06.87 %
-----------------   --------------- ------------------------------  --- ------------
TOTAL       873/873     1           =   100 %
```

I don't know if the `Frames` field is the key here.

Comment: Beware that since 802.11 does not have a single fixed data rate, the real thing you should be measuring is airtime, not bits. So take the length in bits of each packet, and divide it by the PHY rate (in bits per second) that was used for that packet, to find the airtime (in seconds) that it used. Do this for every packet, INCLUDING unacknowledged frames and retransmissions, and add up the resulting per-packet airtimes that each client took up. Then compare how much total airtime each client used as a percentage of the total time you were observing the network traffic.

Comment: @Spiff, according to your explanation, I think: 1.- AirCrack-NG doesn't seem to have the capability to show the PHY rate of each client, so we should find another tool... it it exists. 2.- Identifying unacknowledges and retransmissions requires data mining, and that is not a problem except for the need of decryption. Isn't WPA supposed to not allow network sniffing of another clients even knowing the key (passphrase)?